# Is it possible to upgrade version without grub?

Tags: grub2, ubuntu-gnome, grub-efi

My Ubuntu is asking to update from 19.04 to 19.10. the thing is I have more distros installed and I don't want grub being installed in Ubuntu. When I do do-release-upgrade it forces to install grub

Comment: I thought it ran `update-grub` and not `grub-install`, but regardless I'd just let it do it's normal thing - then change the MBR back to what whichever OS you want to own it; it's not difficult.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I think I'll do that way. Yes although grub isn't installed the version upgrade will install grub in the system. I know also you can put an exclusion filter in apt , but didn't work to upgrade

Comment: Even if packages are installed, the `grub-install` isn't called I still believe, the grub config files are just created or re-created, so the owner of your MBR won't change.